# Handling datetime microseconds with Rails5 and MySQL5.6.4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

- Rails5+
- MySQL5.6.4+

Specifying precision with datetime type works as expected.

```
# migration
create_table :micro_articles do |t|
  t.timestamps precision: 6
end

# test data
MicroArticle.create(created_at: '2017-05-09T12:34:56.123456+09:00')


MicroArticle.where(created_at: DateTime.now).to_sql
=> SELECT `micro_articles`.* FROM `micro_articles` WHERE (created_at = '2017-05-09T12:34:56.123456+09:00')

MicroArticle.where("created_at < ?", DateTime.now).to_sql
=> SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (created_at < '2017-05-09T12:34:56.123456+09:00')
```

However, if I don't specify it, the range search does not work as expected.

```
# migration
create_table :articles do |t|
  t.timestamps
end

# test data
Article.create(created_at: '2017-05-09T12:34:56+09:00')

Article.where(created_at: DateTime.now).to_sql
=> SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (created_at = '2017-05-09T12:34:56+09:00')
# OK

Article.where("created_at < ?", DateTime.now).to_sql
=> SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (created_at < '2017-05-09T12:34:56.123456+09:00')
# Expect SQL
#=> SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (created_at < '2017-05-09T12:34:56+09:00')
```

I have avoided this way, but is there a better way?

```
Article.where("created_at < ?", DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).to_sql
=> SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE (created_at < '2017-05-09T12:34:56+09:00')
```